# Deriving the formula of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

Let $(a,b)\in\mathbb{C^2}$ such that $(a,b)\neq0$

Let $x\in\mathbb{C/\{0\}}$ such that $x^2=ax+b$

Now, $$x^2=ax+b$$
$$\iff x^3= ax^2+bx$$
$$\iff x^3 = a(ax+b)+bx$$
$$\iff x^3 = (a^2+b)x+ab$$
$$\iff x^4 = (a^2+b)x^2 +abx$$
$$\iff x^4 = (a^2+b)(ax+b)+abx$$
$$\iff x^4 = (a^3+2ab)x + a^{2}b + b^2$$

and so on we can go on writing $x^n$; where $n\in\mathbb{N}\space|\space n \geq 3$; as a linear expression in $x$

Is there a way to derive the coefficient of $x$ and the constant term in this linear expression for $x^n$ . If yes, can I get a hint on how to do so?  I can observe that these coefficients and constant terms form a sequence so there must be some general expression for them.

Any hint will be appreciated, Thank You.

Comment: You don't use $a_2,b_2$ after saying they aren't zero. It seems you only use $a,b$ [with no subscripts]. Should there be a relation connecting $a,b,a_2,b_2$?

Comment: @coffeemath I'm sorry that was merely a typing error, thanks for pointing it out, I've corrected it in the question

Comment: @neofyt: This question seems largely similar to your [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4545860/409). Please explain how this one is different (as I may be overlooking some important nuance) to avoid having this question closed as a duplicate. (If you're effectively asking the same question in a different way, then you should just edit the previous question.)

Comment: @Blue The last one I asked was a  pretty cumbersome and confusing of this current one, I was going to delete it a little later, thanks for the reminder, I'm deleting that one

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ x^n=a_nx+b_n. $$
and then
$$ x^{n+1}=a_{n+1}x+b_{n+1}=xx^n=x(a_nx+b_n)=a_nx^2+b_nx=a_n(ax+b)+b_nx. $$
So
$$ a_{n+1}=aa_n+b_n, b_{n+1}=ba_n $$
for $n=2,3,\cdots$. Here $a_2=a,b_2=b$.

Comment: That's exactly what neofyt did in a previous question, and this would only work if we had this for all x, or for at least a sufficient amount of x